# Linear gradient animation not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation

Could someone explain why linear gradient animation does not work in Firefox (Latest version). In all other browsers it is working just fine.

```css
.pop_up_caller_bg_form_timer_time:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  animation: circle_progress 2s ease infinite;
}

@-moz-keyframes circle_progress {
  0% {
    background: #cdeb8e;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #cdeb8e 0%, #a5c956 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
  }
  100% {
    background: #1e5799;
    /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%);
    /* FF3.6+ */
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="pop_up_caller_bg_form_timer_time"></div>
```

Also i uploaded code on http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXwjWo

Answer (score 0):

i guess the problem is that firefox doesn't need a -moz- prefix on gradients. So remove the -moz- prefixes on background: linear-gradient(top, #cdeb8e 0%, #a5c956 100%); and it should work.

Comment: I tried removing them, but it did not make any changes. I mean it still not working..

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 Animations was [unprefixed](http://paulrouget.com/e/unprefixing-in-firefox-16/) in Firefox 16. So just remove `-moz` prefix. Also note that `linear-gradient` [has another syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) than `-moz-linear-gradient`. This will work fine:

```
@keyframes circle_progress {
  0% {
    background: #cdeb8e; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #cdeb8e 0%, #a5c956 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  }

  100% {
    background: #1e5799; /* Old browsers */
    background: linear-gradient(top, #1e5799 0%, #2989d8 50%, #207cca 51%, #7db9e8 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
  }

}
```

Comment: Nope, just applied fixes which you wrote and it does not solve problem

Comment: Edit answer, changed `to top` to `top`. All works fine.

Comment: Yes, but it is not gradient, it is solid color